# pass javascript sessionStorage variable to php to insert to mySQL - form not an option

Tags: javascript, php, bitnami

I have been asked to take upon to complete a small mini-project which was left incomplete by a previous front-end developer. The background is, there are 3 html pages with client-side javascript which takes the user input and stores it in a sessionStorage variable. On the second html page, it's the same thing, user response is stored in sessionStorage and finally on the third html page, the user provided data is displayed neatly, very nifty for  use within a single user browser session. Now i have been asked to store the data in a backend mysql database. Now please understand that i am system admin and i have only worked on bits and pieces on coding. There is no one at the mo who can help me and i need to get this before the week is out. i have made a copy of the final.html page as final.php and running out from my localhost server, no problems  with that.
Could someone please advice me on the quickest way to get this javascript variables to php variables and then i can  do the mysql insert statements? Please due to time constraints, forms POST/GET submission is out as i don't want  to redesign the whole thing. I was looking at cookies, hidden fields, PHP Sessions?

Sample:

```
<script>
sessionStorage.setItem("myvar1","1234");
var temper = sessionStorage.getItem("myvar1");
alert(temper);
</script>

<?php

// need help here....
?>
```

Regards,

Ochen

Comment: There is no way to access sessionStorage data form PHP. You have to send these variables via GET or POST request to server.

Comment: don't make a form , try post request in Ajax way. from ajax fire a post request with session storage object as payload to php and rest is simple post and mysql stuff in php

Comment: or simply on the "final page" , when page loads , just make a form (post req) there with input type hidden , and fill all the values from session storage and submit. (as input type hidden nothing will be visible and you will have a form behind the scene)

Comment: you mean something like this on the final.php page...

Comment: <form method="POST" action="final.php"><input type="hidden"><input type="submit"></form>

Comment: sorry on the second.html page

Comment: or if you could share a sample ajax post submission on that page itself.... i just need php to be able to get those variable values... the rest i can handle...

Comment: ok i have added <input  type="hidden" and i do confirm that i have a validation js function before it gets submitted and the value gets populated when i do an alert(document.getElementById("inputname").value); Now on the finalpage.php i get undefined index inputname   error. I have also wrapped isset function but no joy... The input type hidden is within the form and i am using post method...

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your feedbacks. This  is now fixed.